# How to convert List<Class A> to Map<String, List<Class B>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have some scenarios have to convert object from `List<Class A>` to `Map<String, List<Class B>>`. What I try to attempt is to group info by one of the field in Class A and remove useless field from class A (result in class B)

Currently, I can do this by below sample code.

```java
// Raw data input
List<TestClass> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Add items here...

// group by field
Map<String, List<TestClass>> result = itemList.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TestClass::getUsername));

// Reform every single list and add to a new Map
Map<String, List<TestClassShort>> tcsMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<TestClass>> tc: result.entrySet()) {
    tcsMap.put(tc.getKey(), 
               tc.getValue().stream()
               .map(x -> new TestClassShort(x.getGroupId(), x.getGroupName()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the goal without creating an extra HashMap in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a downstream Collector with `groupingBy`.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

// declare for readability, I found it ugly inline
Function<TestClass, TestClassShort> shorten = 
             x -> new TestClassShort(x.getGroupId(), x.getGroupName());

Map<String, List<TestClassShort>> result = itemList.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(TestClass::getUsername,mapping(shorten, toList())));
```

Comment: I somehow find unreadable the usage of static methods such as `groupingBy`, `mapping` and `toList` without the prefix `Collectors` which indicates where it comes from. :/

Comment: @Nikolas Yeah that's a matter of taste obviously. I usually import the ones I use often and leave `Collectors` in for the less common ones. In this case, I'd import `groupingBy` and `toList`, but not `mapping`. I just wanted to keep the actual code snippet short here, but added the actual imports to avoid people getting too confused.